# Detect mouse click on canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I currently have a problematic situation -
I have a re-sizing canvas (re-sized based on resize event) that has some rectangle being drawn on it, these rectangles has X,Y, WIDTH and HEIGHT properties now...
 When I resize the canvas everything is good and the shapes are being drawed relatively to the canvas size.
The problem is that their X and Y aren't changing, so when I try to use any mouse events to detect if the mouse position is inside a rectangle it doesn't work except for the beggining, so for example -
If I initialize everything when the window size is 1024*768 for example so the rectangle X and Y position would be 50 by 50, if I'll click with my mouse on X:50 it will collide and detect it, but, if I'll resize my browser's window to  let's say, 689*400 and I'll click on the rectangle it won't work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

TL;DR - How can I detect a click on rectangle that has X,Y after re-sizing the window?

Canvas resizing -

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                        self.canvas.fitToBrowser();
                    });

Kanivas.prototype.fitToBrowser = function() {
    if (this.canvas.width < window.innerWidth)
    {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.cHeight = this.canvas.width;
    }

    if (this.canvas.height < window.innerHeight)
    {
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.cHeight = this.canvas.height;
    }
};
```

MouseDown handler -

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",
            function(kanivas, event) {
                console.log(state);
                self.mouseDownHandler(kanivas, event);
            }.bind(null, this), false);

Kanivas.prototype.mouseDownHandler = function(kanivas, e) {
    var shape = null;
    var i = kanivas.shapes.length;
    while (i--) {
        shape = kanivas.shapes[i];
        if (shape.isInside !== undefined && shape.isInside(e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
            shape.mouseDownHandler();
        }
    }
};
 //Inside the rectangle object
 this.isInside = function(x, y) {
        return ((x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.width) &&
                (y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.height));
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your current code? For example your resizing code and your code for detecting collision.

Comment: I think you need to resize the context as well

Comment: @JonasGrumann What do you mean?

Comment: You didn't show the part of the code that draws/handles the scaling. Best would be to create a working jsfiddle for us to see/fix the issue. You must ensure that the scaled applied to the rects is applied to the mouse coordinates also.

Comment: I've fixed it using the ratio between the last window size and the new window size, I'll update my answer tomorrow:
RatioWidth = WindowWidthA/WindowWidthB
ObjectX /= RatioWidth